# What does it mean by "Window of opportunity"

Tags: idioms

What is mean by "Window of opportunity"

Comment: related phrase is "window of (duration)" to express a duration. For example, a *one-month window* is a period beginning at some point and ending one month later

Comment: *Window of opportunity" actually appears as a phrase in many online dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

It is a period of time during which it is possible to do something that is otherwise unattainable out of that time frame.

Comment: Does this not mean as a "Chance to escape". eg. Cat drink milk and run away through window. Which becomes "Window of opportunity"

Comment: @mujaffars:If the cat only had a few seconds to escape before the window (or the door) got closed, those seconds would be the window of opportunity (the only period of time during which the cat would have the chance to get out).